# Powershell - results come into variable as @{name=SOMEVALUE}... isthere a better way?

Tags: powershell

I am learning PowerShell, and when I try to put some values into a variable, and then loop through those values, the actual result isn't what I'd expect. In the below example, I'd expect just the server name to be returned, but instead I get the result as shown as the bottom.  I know I could technically probably remove `@{name=` with some string manipulation, but surely there is a better way? Thanks.

```
$serverlist = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "*windows*server*"} -Properties DNSHostName | select name
    Foreach ($server in $serverlist)
        {
            #Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" } -ComputerName $server | select PSComputerName, Name, SID, PrincipalSource
            Write-Host $server
        }

        # RESULT is @{name=SOMESERVERNAME}
```

I would expect my variable $server to just show the name.

Comment: remove `Write-Host` and change `select name` to `select -Expand name`

Comment: thanks - that fixed it.  the write-host is just for testing.

Comment: In short: [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (`select`) by default returns _a `[pscustomobject]` instance_ that has the _requested properties_ - even when you're only asking for a _single_ property. To get only that property's _value_, use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter instead of the (possibly positionally implied) `-Property` parameter. See the linked duplicate for details and alternatives, notably the ability to simply use `(...).SomeProperty`

Comment: As for using `Write-Host` for _diagnostic, to-display_  output (it cannot output _data_): Note that it doesn't use the rich rendering of complex objects that you get by default - essentially, `Write-Host` calls `.ToString()` on its arguments and outputs multiple arguments on the same line. If you want direct-to-display output with rich formatting, use `... | Out-Host`.